# I want to put a variable type in a certain place in a string

Tags: c, string

Let's say I have 2 char's.

```c
char* string = "hello";
char* insert = "inserting";
```

If I wanted to put the `inserting` in front of the two L's in `string` yet behind the O, how would I do such.  Bear in mind, I am new to C so any tips you guys have would be well appreciated.

Comment: "put a variable type in a certain place in a string" from the title does not seem to match what you describe in the body of your post. Please clarify.

Comment: You would first need something other than *String-Literals* to avoid Segfaulting... `char string[64] = "hello";` would be a better starting point. (`char *string = "hello";` assigns the address of the immutable *String-Literal* `"hello"` to `string`. Any attempt to modify `"hello"` will result in very bad things happening) `char string[64] = "hello";` initializes a 64-character array with the letters in `"hello"` which are then fully modifiable.

Comment: How do you place something in front of the two L in `"hello"` but behind the O? You actually mean how to insert something between the two L and the O, yes?

Comment: To Lundin, I am talking more about something like ```hellinsertingo```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a string into another you could use something like this:

```
  char* string = "hello";            
  char* insert = "inserting"; 
  char result[20];                      //resulting string

  int position = 4;                     //position to insert 
  
  strncpy(result, string, position);      // copy position char's from string into result
  result[position] = '\0';                //strings in c end with '\0' you need this for the strcat next
  strcat(result, insert);                  //join the previous result with the insert string
  strcat(result, string + position);    //tricky one, join the previous result with the initial string after position char's 
  printf("%s\n", result);
```

But you need the position that you want to insert the second string into the first one, in your case to get that you could use strchr(string,'o') to get the position of the first o in 'hello', like:

```
  char * aux = strchr(string, 'o');
  int index = (int)(aux - string);
```

Now "index" should have the value 4, that's the position I predefined before.

Comment: Teaching newbies to use `strncpy` and at the same time add a manual `'\0'` isn't good advise. The dangerous `strncpy` function adds the null terminator, but only if there is room. If not, `strncpy` will create bugs. In this case you told it there's only 4 characters of space, so the function thinks there isn't any room. For those not aware of this (like newbies), `strncpy` shouldn't be used and `memcpy` would probably have been preferred.